# protoc command show Missing input file

Tags: 18.04, google, protocol

I installed protobuf using following command.

> sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler

When I hit the

> protoc --version

it show version as libprotoc 3.0.0

But when I try to hit the `protoc` in terminal it shows `Missing input file`.

How can I fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

`protoc` is the compiler for protocol buffer, you need to provide the `.proto` file to compile.

Consider this java example-

`protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto`